# MvvmCross ExoPlayer Sample causes "System.TypeLoadException: Type '__callback_factory__class__' is not finished"

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to use the [ExoPlayerXamarin sample](https://github.com/martijn00/ExoPlayerXamarin) but have been running into several issues. The first issue being that the sample had insufficient project settings and resources (i.e. no Android manifest). The next problem was that the Activity attribute was missing "MainLauncher = true".

Now I am running into another problem. When debugging the sample, during initialization I get:

> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.

Full stack trace below. The class in question is `__class_factory__` and is a dynamic class. The exception is caused because MvvmCross initialization in [FindSetupType](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/8a824c797747f74716fc64c2fd0e8765c29b16ab/MvvmCross/Droid/Droid/Platform/MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.cs#L150) is looking for a specific type in the assembly but this dynamic assembly is not yet ready and causes a crash.

I just want to use the sample... does anybody know how I can work around this?

Thanks

```
System.TypeLoadException: Type '__callback_factory__class__' is not finished

System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
  at System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder.GetTypes (System.Boolean exportedOnly) [0x00145] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/c1d1c79c/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection.Emit/AssemblyBuilder.cs:756 
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/c1d1c79c/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:405 
  at System.Reflection.Assembly+<>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x00021] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/c1d1c79c/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:999 
  at MvvmCross.Platform.ReflectionExtensions+<GetTypes>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00064] in D:\git\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Platform\Platform\ReflectionExtensions.cs:12 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+<SelectManyIterator>c__Iterator5`3[TSource,TCollection,TResult].MoveNext () [0x0009a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/c1d1c79c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:472 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () [0x00078] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/c1d1c79c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:282 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x0003e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/c1d1c79c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:976 
  at MvvmCross.Droid.Platform.MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.FindSetupType () [0x000b9] in <c9cff602f1404a9da5c69389736fa297>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Droid.Platform.MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.CreateSetup (Android.Content.Context applicationContext) [0x00000] in <c9cff602f1404a9da5c69389736fa297>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Droid.Platform.MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable (Android.Content.Context applicationContext) [0x00031] in <c9cff602f1404a9da5c69389736fa297>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityViewExtensions.EnsureSetupInitialized (MvvmCross.Droid.Views.IMvxAndroidView androidView) [0x00014] in <c9cff602f1404a9da5c69389736fa297>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityViewExtensions.OnViewCreate (MvvmCross.Droid.Views.IMvxAndroidView androidView, Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x0000d] in <c9cff602f1404a9da5c69389736fa297>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityAdapter.EventSourceOnCreateCalled (System.Object sender, MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1[T] eventArgs) [0x0000c] in <c9cff602f1404a9da5c69389736fa297>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.EventHandler`1[MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1[Android.OS.Bundle]]:invoke_void_object_TEventArgs (object,MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1<Android.OS.Bundle>)
  at MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxDelegateExtensionMethods.Raise[T] (System.EventHandler`1[TEventArgs] eventHandler, System.Object sender, T value) [0x00000] in D:\git\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Platform\Platform\Core\MvxDelegateExtensionMethods.cs:21 
  at MvvmCross.Platform.Droid.Views.MvxEventSourceActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00014] in <927906a0a3f249d6bfc8757c0c8bdde7>:0 
  at MvvmCross.ExoPlayer.Droid.MvxVideoPlayerActivity`1[TViewModel].OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x00002] in C:\Users\agendum\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MvvmCross\ExoPlayer.Droid\MvxVideoPlayerActivity.cs:145
```

Comment: Does this also happen if you initialize it somewhere else? I suspect that MvvmCross has nothing at all to do with this.

Comment: Thanks for your response Cheesebaron. I am not sure what you mean by initialize it somewhere else. I have tried the solution in both VIsual Studio 2015 and Xamarin Studio and both give the same result. I did try other MvvmCross samples and did not run into this problem, so it seems the problem is isolated to this solution.